# Renaming the optimized files in requirejs folder level optimization

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-requirejs

I'm using requirejs with Grunt in my project. I could able to successfully perform the folder level optimization through `grunt-requirejs` tool as below.

```
requirejs : {
    std: {
        options: {
            mainConfigFile: 'src/js/main.js',
        appDir: "src",
        baseUrl: "js",
        dir: "dist",
        modules: [
            {
                name: "main"
            }
        ],
        removeCombined: true,
        wrap: true,
        almond: true,
      replaceRequireScript: [{
        files: ['dist/index.html'],
        module: 'main'
      }]
    }
    }
}
```

All the js files are concatenated and minified in `main.js` and css files in `style.css`. How can I rename these files `main.js` and `style.css` into something like `app.min.js` and `app.min.css`. Can I able to accomplish this using `r.js` or I've to use some external plugin?